# Creating docker image that executes commands in python virtualenv

Tags: docker, virtualenv

I have the following problem ...

I want to create a docker image on which a python virtual environment is created. Then I want to be able to do the following two things:

- Run `docker run -it <image>` to start an interactive shell in this virtual environment.
- Run `docker run <image> <command>` (such as `python --version`) that is executed in said virtual environment.

I tried many things but it seems I don't get anywhere. My Dockerfile looks currently like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y python3 python-pip
RUN pip install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv -p python3.5 /venvs/myenv3.5
RUN . /venvs/myenv3.5/bin/activate && pip install bumpy
```

I tried messing around with `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` but I don't get anywhere. By adding the following line: `CMD . /venvs/myenv3.5/bin/activate; /bin/bash;` I was able to start an interactive bash in the environment, but running `docker run <image> python --version` shows that commands like that are not executed in said environment.

Is there a way to do this?